# WCF Callback Timer

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF service hosted in a Windows service. This uses the Publish Subscribe pattern to post events to multiple subscribers. However, I am finding that after a length of inactivity, the connection fails and I get reliable session was faulted errors. I have tried to fix this by changing the inactivity timeout and receive timout settings but it makes no difference. It's driving me mad to be honest.

A solution I have seen mentioned is to "ping" all the subscribers every so often. (for example half the length of the timeout).

What would be the best way of setting up a "ping" like this? i.e. how do I add a timer to the service and how to get that timer to call a ping function?

**EDIT:**

I am not totally happy with the ping solution and would like to investigate further why my reliable session keeps timing out. Below is the binding configuration for this service

Server app.config

```
<binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_IError" receiveTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000">
    <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000" />
</binding>
```

Client app.config

```
<binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_IError" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000"
    sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false"
    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000" />
    <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
            algorithmSuite="Default" />
    </security>
</binding>
```

I tried "infinite" rather then this value but it didn't like it. Said the value was invalid even though several pages from a Google search suggested doing this. I can only assume this was valid in an earlier version of WCF/.NET

**EDIT2:**

Here is the exception log. It definitely does seem to be a random amount of time.

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.TimeoutException: The operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:00:59.4979498. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.InterruptibleWaitObject.Wait(TimeSpan timeout, Boolean throwTimeoutException)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableInputConnection.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableDuplexSessionChannel.OnClose(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableDuplexSessionChannel.OnClose(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnClose(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.Close()
   at MyApp.Form1.buttonError_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: Can you post your configuration code or config file where you set up the timeouts? What is the exact exception and the code where the exception is thrown?

Comment: I've wasted too much time already trying to solve the timeout issue. I just want to know how to setup the ping stuff. Thanks though.

Comment: @Jonnster *to ping* is the wrong way to go. You will create a hacky solution that will bite you back in the bottom.

Comment: @oleksii: i don't think its totally wrong. A benefit of pinging is that you can catch orphaned connections long before your tcp stack will inform you.

Comment: I've update the original post with the app.config settings as I would prefer to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Ok, more questions: How long is the period till your exception occurs?  Is it always exactly the same period? Where is the exception thrown? Can you post the stacktrace and the exact exception with all inner exceptions?

Comment: To be honest, I haven't narrowed down the exact timeframe and whether it is always the same. I am going to do some further testing to check this but it did seem fairly random. I'll post the stack trace and exception details next time I hit it today.

Comment: I can't reproduce this at the moment. I left it running last night and this morning it caused the same problem but now it seems okay. It will definitely fault at some point though.

Comment: Ok, to get on the ground of that i would recommend to enable wcf message tracing and logging (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732009.aspx for information on the Configuration Editor Tool (SvcConfigEditor.exe)). And it might be helpful to attach handlers to the channel events Close and Faulted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For implementing the pinging of your clients you may want to follow this list of steps:

1. Extend your callback contract with a Ping method (you should have already a callback contract because you wrote you use the publish subscribe pattern, havn't you?):

   ```
   [OperationContract]
   void Ping();
   ```
2. In the operation the clients call first after connecting, store a reference to the clients operation context in a collection:

   ```
   List<OperationContext> _clientCtxList = new List<OperationContext>();

   void IMyService.InitSession() {
       _clientCtxList.Add(OperationContext.Current);
   }
   ```
3. Define a function, called by your timer to ping all the clients:

   ```
   void tmrPing (object state) {
       foreach (var ctx in _clientCtxList)
       {
           // todo: catch exceptions and remove client context 
           //       from list in case of failure
           ctx.GetCallbackChannel<IMyCallbackContract>().Ping();
       }

       // restart timer
       _timer.Change(10000, Timeout.Infinite);
   }
   ```
4. Define and start a timer when your service starts up (i'm not aware of IIS hosting, so you have to find the right location for this yourself):

   ```
   System.Threading.Timer _timer;

   void Startup() {
       // call my function in 10 seconds
       _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
                       tmrPing, null, 10000, Timeout.Infinte);
   }
   ```

Remarks:

- This is notepad code - it might contain syntactic errors and might not compile.
- Exception handling is not included
- locking of the _clineCtxList is not included but highly recommended

Comment: This solution will work, but pls consider the following: `ping` does not have any business value but takes space in the contract, it requires additional code, thus probability of bugs rises, it adds absolutely unnecessary complexity to the code, it slightly increases load on the service, it needs documentation and further code maintenance. All this can be fixed by the initial correct binding configuration. This is why I would suggest to fix the root problem, rather than use a hack.

Comment: Yes, maybe. But the op explicitly asked for a ping-solution

Comment: @oleksii - I agree with you totally but the fact is WCF sucks. It really is rubbish. Bring back the days of COM, COM+ and DCOM. Life was so much easier and STUFF ACTUALLY WORKED! WCF in comparisn is just rubbish in my opinion. Of course I would love to find the solution but Google suggests this is a widespread problem and some even suggest it is a known bug which MS won't fix.

Comment: Thanks Jan. This was pretty much what I was thinking of so nice to have the idea backed up so to speak. I am reluctant to code it though as I do agree it feels a bit like skirting around the issue.

Comment: Its not rubbish but its quite complex because the architecture is very extensible and configurable in every known and unknwon direction. Sometimes its hard to find the right property to change for changing the behaviour to your needs. Maybe you should give us more information about the binding and the timeout values you use.

Comment: I've update the original post with the app.config settings as I would prefer to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: To be honest WCF is no more complicated than COM+ but it seemed a lot more stable to me. I preferred working with COM/COM+ but times move on.